# Symfony accessing mp3 files outside of web directory to play in browser

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, audio

How can I get access an mp3 inside of app/Resources/userFiles/mp3s directory? Inside of my controller I render a view that has [audio] tag but I need to get access to the mp3 file which is outside of the web directory.

1. An ajax call is made to request the mp3 file (done).
2. In my controller I want to grab the mp3 in that directory such as this:

   ```
   $track = "file.mp3";
   $fileLocation = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/Resources/userFiles/mp3s/'.$track;
   ```
3. Then pass that mp3 to a template which has an [audio] tag.

   ```
   $trackHtml = $this->renderView('MyBundle:Public:track.html.twig', array(
       'id'=>$request->request->get("id"),
       'fileLocation'=>$fileLocation,
   ));
   ```
4. Then send the response back via ajax so that the user can hear the audio  on page which has been set up in the [audio] tag (done).

   ```
   $data = array(
      "track"=>$trackHtml,
   );
   return new JsonResponse($data);
   ```

Bottomline, I dont know how to get access to that mp3 to display it publicly.

```
is_file($fileLocation = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/Resources/userFiles/mp3s/'.$track) is TRUE,
```

I just cant make the file public.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28760854/1791606

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `app/Resources` from the web. This folder mainly used for overriding templates and storing assets (js and css files). According to the latest symfony2 best practice ([Web Assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html)) even assets should be stored inside web directory.

1. You could make symbolic link inside web directory to `app/Resources/mp3`.
2. Entirely move it under web.
3. Use custom action to output file content to the browser.